# Curl request for most recent records

Tags: curl

I know nothing about CURL what so ever but I am trying to get data from a server, they provide a request template but I can't seem to get the most recent data.

curl -X GET https://www.*******.com/public-api/v1/locations/5156708552802304/data?startTime=0

This request only gets me the first 20 records ever recorded, what I want is the last 20 or very least the most current one. I can obviously put in the current unix timestamp 1552930900, but every time I send the request I would have to change that value is there someway to put in a *current-time* -1000 or something that would make this curl request repeatable for the most current data?

Comment: CURL basically just makes an HTTP request to the endpoint. Looking at the endpoint, there is a startTime parameter that seems like can be what you're looking for. With that being said, it's hard to say without full documentation for the endpoint. Do you have that documentation available?

Comment: Really just about nothing just this section                                                   Reading{
description: 

Represents a single data point. The time and value of the reading
timestamp integer($int64)
allowEmptyValue: false

Epoch time in seconds when this reading was recorded
value number($double)
allowEmptyValue: false

The value of this reading. If there was more than 1 reading in this minute, this value will be the average of all the readings during that minute.